# How to upgrade Portable Python 2.X after installation / deployment

Tags: python-2.7, upgrade, portable-applications

I had recently installed Portable Python 2.7.6.1 from [Portable Python](http://portablepython.com/), and I understand that the latest Python version of the 2.X family is 2.7.9.

I am wondering if it is possible for me to upgrade my installation of Portable Python, after I had deployed it on my USB? If it is possible, please show me the way.

If this question had already been answered (although I had searched and researched quite a bit), please point me the question. I am more than happy to close this question and offer my apologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may be wrong - but just to provide anyone who stumbled upon this - there is no way I can upgrade the python interpreter that comes with the portable python package.

Eventually I switched to [WinPython](http://winpython.github.io/) instead. It seems like there is no easy way to upgrade itself either, but for a portable environment, it can be replaced by downloading the newer version from project homepage.

Edit:
I may be too early in my response, I think Anaconda distribution has an ability to update itself by:

```
conda update all
```